# combining Yenc files into 1 file

Tags: php

Hay guys, I'm writing a PHP application to take a NZB file, grab the Yenc files from that, download them, then combine them, then decode them back into binary state.

I've managed the first part, but I'm having trouble combining the Yenc files back into 1 Yenc file.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.newznab.com/ is an open source PHP application that does similar things you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [yEnc PHP Class](http://everything2.com/title/yEnc+PHP+Class)? That should handle your decoding problem?

If the only problem remaining is combining the parts, have you tried a simple binary-safe append?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but what was the problem. you would need to instantiate it first, e.g. `$yEnc = new yenc(); $yEnc->decode(...)` Also note that it was written in 2002 so it is written for php4. You may need to debug it a little to make it work in php5.

Answer (score 0):

Answering a very old post, but it may help others.

Once you have all the parts of the file decoded, you just need to merge the raw bytes together.

So in sudo code:

byte[] file1Decoded
byte[] file2Decoded

byte[] completeFile = file1Decoded + file2Decoded